# Lumen Collective-HTML Form

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I have created a small test-project and wanted to use this:
https://github.com/vluzrmos/collective-html

I have done the same things step by step as in the manual. But I got this error:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

In the app.php I enabled this:

```
$app->withFacades();

$app->withEloquent();
```

And added the register and alias as given in the manual. Also I changed in the index.php that the requests are working.
My route and my controller are working. If I write only html content the page is fully and correctly shown.

But If I change my blade-template and at this:

```
{!! $form->open() !!}

{!! $html->asset() !!}
```

It doesn't work. And the error which I have given before occurs and the page is not shown.

Is the call wrong or should I declare anything in my Controller or in the head of the View?

By the way, the files/library are/is existing and loaded via composer

(Lumen 5.2)

Answer (score 0):

to use this way:

```
{!! $form->open() !!}
```

you need to put this on bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register('Collective\Html\InjectVarsServiceProvider');
```

Or you can  just use like this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/test')) !!}
```